# Batch file to run cmd command

Tags: batch-file, cmd, bulk

I have this cmd command (that I found here) that makes me list all image files in the current folder:

`for %i in (*) do echo ^<img src="%i" /^> >> all.html`

So if I want to run this I need to go to cmd and manually input the folder path every time I run said code.

Can I put this in a batch file/cmd file so I can just put the batch file/cmd file in any folder I want and it will run the code?

Comment: What OS and language is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for `%~DP0` which is only available within a batch file and displays the current drive and directory in which that batch file is located *note, this cannot change*. It is obtained from `%0` which is the batch file's name.

`%CD%` on the other hand is available either to a batch file or at the command prompt and expands to the drive letter and path of the current directory. *Which could change by using `CD` for instance*.

[More info](https://ss64.com/nt/cd.html)

## Full answer is given by [Compo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6738015/compo):

```
@(for %%i in ("%~dp0*") do @echo ^<img src="%%i" /^>)>"all.html"
```

Comment: Like this, `@(for %%i in ("%~dp0*") do @echo ^<img src="%%i" /^>)>"all.html"`